# Segmentation fault trying to send message to client from server

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault

I need to send a message to a client and then the client have to respond with an option. I get till the client and server connects, but both program end with "Segmentation Fault". Does anyone knows what this error means? Can someone give an idea to how to create a code that will make client and server interact. After receiving the option chosen by the client the server have to analyze it and send again a result to client.

My codes are:

Server

```
    int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 listenfd, connfd;
    socklen_t           len;
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr, cliaddr;
    char                buff[MAXLINE];
    time_t              ticks;
    char                message[MAXLINE]="This is the server";
    char                temp_scale[2];
    char                recvdata[MAXLINE + 1];

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);/*----------------------------------------------------*/
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(5555); 

    Bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &len);

        printf("Connection from %s, port %d\n",
               Inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, buff, sizeof(buff)),
               ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port));


        snprintf(message, sizeof(message), "%s\r\n");
            Writen(connfd, message, strlen(message));
            while ( (n = read(connfd, recvdata, MAXLINE)) > 0)
            {
             recvdata[n] = 0;   /* null terminate*/
             if (fputs(recvdata, stdout) == EOF)
                 err_sys("fputs error");
            }
             if (n < 0)
          err_sys("read error");

           Close(connfd);
    }
}
```

Client

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 sockfd, rd;
    socklen_t           len;
    char                recvline[MAXLINE + 1];
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr, cliaddr;
    char  scale[2];

    /*if (argc != 2)
        err_quit("usage: a.out <IPaddress>");*/

    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        err_sys("socket error");

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port   = htons(atoi(argv[2])); /*port passed through command line*/
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0) /*The client translates the server address, passed on the command line*/
        err_quit("inet_pton error for %s", argv[1]);


    if (connect(sockfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
        err_sys("connect error");

    len = sizeof(cliaddr);
    Getsockname(sockfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &len);
    printf("Local Address is: %s\n",
           Sock_ntop((SA *) &cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr))); 

    printf("Iniciando read...\n");
    while ( (rd = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) > 0)
    {
        recvline[rd] = 0;   /* null terminate*/
        if (fputs(recvline, stdout) == EOF)
            err_sys("fputs error");
    }
    if (rd < 0)
     err_sys("read error");

    printf("Enter option 'A' or 'B'");
    send_scale(sockfd);

    exit(0);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Segmentation fault means you have are accessing forbidden memory, ie you have a bug related to invalid or pointers or array out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Any particular reason some buffers have length MAXLINE, but some have MAXLINE+1? Without understanding the code, this smells like a bug.

Comment: Thank you, so I can I know how to fix this? I use the same functions in client and server, does this is making the problem?

Comment: I found it in a book, it says that +1 is for the termination character (NULL)

Comment: Then why aren't you consistently allocation room for the null character, but only in some of the places?

Comment: I'm only allocating for the receiving lines. It what the book says you need to do. I'm new in C programming and suddenly I have to create a server and a client. I haven't even program more than basic programming in C...so I'm taking examples

Comment: Compile your sources with all warnings on (`-Wall`for `gcc`), fix the code until you get no more warnings, then compile it using symbols (`-g` for  `gcc`) and run the program(s) using a debugger (`gdb` for `gcc`) and see where it crashes.

Comment: your receiving lines will also contain '\0' if its a c-string. so always allocate +1 for receiving strings too\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is probably faulting because of this:

```
snprintf(message, sizeof(message), "%s\r\n"); // <== no parameters
```

It is flat-out wrong. The `snprintf()` call has a format specifier that is expecting a `char *` to a null-terminated string, and you're passing it absolutely nothing. It is therefore grabbing a random value out of the stack, treating it as a pointer, and dereferencing it in attempt to fulfill the formatted request.

Without knowing the details of the API you're using (it clearly isn't standard BSD sockets just by the names alone) there isn't much more to go on.

Comment: Thank you WhozCraig! It was that, I have it a string and worked! Now I'm struct in the reading part, I send the message from the server to the client but the client don' receive it. And both client and server stay in blocking read (the server expect an answer from client). Do you know what it's happening?

Comment: @netfreak I don't, but I'll stare awhile and see if it leaps out to me. I'm not a socket-guy, but there are plenty on this site that are, so perhaps one will chime in.

Answer (score 2):

Run your code in a debugger (for example `gdb ./a.out`) and find out in no time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it might help, but in C the null termination for strings is '\0', when you print your response:

```
recvdata[n] = 0;   /* null terminate ----> this must be '\0'*/
if (fputs(recvdata, stdout) == EOF)
err_sys("fputs error");
```

you pad it whith a "0", so it will probably lead you to a segfault when fputs parse your string in order to print it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: In ASCII, `'\0'` == `0`. No harm in being clear and using `'\0'`, though.